# Progress Bar Error at runtime

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-webview

The Program keeps crashing when i try to run it on my handset. cant figure out why it is crashing

Main java

```
public class ProgressBar extends Activity {

WebView webview;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
setContentView(R.layout.main );
 final Activity MyActivity = this;

// Makes Progress bar Visible
getWindow().setFeatureInt( Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);

webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)   
    {
     //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded, and changes string to Loading...
    MyActivity.setTitle("Loading...");
     MyActivity.setProgress(progress * 100); //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded

     // Return the app name after finish loading
        if(progress == 100)
           MyActivity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
      }
    });

webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");

}
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
    }
    }
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webview.canGoBack()) {
    webview.goBack();
    return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    }
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to find the stacktrace from the crash, you can get this with logcat, either open the logcat view in eclipse (or open the DDMS perspective), or run `adb logcat` from the shell to see the log.

In this case though, i'm pretty sure you'll see any error saying you need to set the window feature before creating any content, move your `setContentView` call to after the `getWindow().requestFeature` call.